# How do I pass a View inside a DatePickerFragment? Using ListView and ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, datepicker, bundle, dialogfragment

I am learning to use Pickers and I am having trouble passing in a View to a DatePickerFragment. Here is a github link to a sample full project source file: https://github.com/MienTommy/DatePickerFragment

And here is the source that implements the DatePickerFragment

```
package com.mienapps.datepickerfragment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TextView>
{
    Activity mContext;
    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<TextView> views)
    {
        super(context, 0, views);
        mContext = context;
    }

    /*Get view from adapter*/
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView datePickerView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);

        datePickerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(mContext.getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }
        });

        return itemView;
    }

    /*Time Picker*/
    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            //TODO: set itemView to the date that is picked. However I can't access it from here.
        }
    }
}
```

On the TODO portion, I want to access itemView so I can set the text to whatever date that the user chose. I cannot use findViewById to reference the TextView because my TextView is part of a ListView.

Comment: you have list of textview and then you want to set date to the views on choosing date from datepicker?

Comment: yes that is what I want to do.

Comment: you can use interface as a callback to the activity and use a model class with getter setter and update views in adapter by calling notifyDateSetChanged on your adapter

Comment: i created a pull request with a basic version of how to do what you just asked in the comment. see if it helps

Comment: I get a NullPointerException at DatePickerFragment.java:68 when running your code.

Comment: the line points to closing brace https://github.com/MienTommy/DatePickerFragment/pull/1/commits/58677582ebee85a637d29bc1ba5c3f4dbec1e99c. You should put the entire stacktrace if you need more help. Link of the snap shot https://postimg.org/image/l6hf3ltgn/

Comment: It shoulda been 67 on that screenshot, however I figured it out, it was because dateSet was being used before the interface was initialized. I had to make setDate a static member and create a static method to initialize it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117471/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tommy-saechao).

Comment: no need to make it static. it should work. got any doubts join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117471/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tommy-saechao

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add an interface on DatePickerFragment and implement that interface in your adapter class , whenever DatePickerFragment updates the date , you can call the interface. In adapter class you can override the interface to do whatever you want. If you are new with interfaces , you can see the example here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm
2. You can store the updated value from DatePickerFragment in a database and while showing list you can read values from database.

Comment: I can't find a way to instantiate the interface. Can you provide an example?